# Is there a way to modify an Image with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, jspdf, html2canvas

So I got a project where the user can generate a pdf based on their input. Using the `jspdf` library to generate the PDF files. The thing is though, the user can upload a profile picture, and I would like to display that image with rounded corners or fully rounded (with a `border-radius` of 50%). Since there isn't a native function that allows this in `jspdf` or any other library as far as I know (`pfdkit`, `pdfmake`), I am looking for a way to modify the image before generating the `pdf`.

I already tried using `html2canvas`, and that worked fine actually. The problem with `html2canvas` occurs when a user is on their mobile. Since the `width` and `height` of the image are adjusted to the screen size (both of which are around `35px`), taking a snapshot with `html2canvas` and then displaying that in a pdf with a width & height of 100px, the image obviously gets way to blurry.

So ideally, I need something to edit the original image or something before generating a PDF file with `jspdf`.

Any other ideas that bring me closer to a solution are also very much appreciated.

Just for clarification, simply adding a CSS property to the image won't help. `jspdf` just uses the image in the `img` tag, without any css properties.

Comment: dont take a snapshot of what's shown on dom, instead do resize in background on original image then use that for the pdf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Rounded Corners for Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171519/javascript-rounded-corners-for-images)

Comment: The screenshot is based on the DOM, so the image has to be on the screen unfortunately. I've tried just placing the image offscreen and taking snapshot. Got a blank image as a result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Canvas drawimage with round corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19585999/canvas-drawimage-with-round-corners)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone for whatever reason stumbles across this post, I managed to actually achieve my desired result. As I said the user is able to upload an image and I would like to display that image with rounded corners or with a border-radius of 50%. Anyway, before previewing (and uploading) the image to my website, the user has to crop the image using `cropperjs`. They can then decide for themselves if they would like to display the image with rounded corners or with a border radius of 50%. I think that gives a tremendous boost to the UX and my end result.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to add a class to the image before you generate the pdf and define the rule for that class in css:

```
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Or, even you may need to force in case there's already css with some border-radius value to img tag:

```
.circle {
  border-radius: 50% !important;
}
```

Comment: I know I can display an image with `img` tag and using `border-radius` to make the rounded corners. But when generating the pdf, it doesn't take the css into account. It just displays the whole images, unmodified. That's why I need to really modify it of some sort before generating a pdf with it.

Comment: Then I must say sorry. Coz, there's no such thing that we can do with just html.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so hehe. This was kinda a longshot.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use rounded images on jspdf, you just need to apply the rounded-ness to the image before adding it to the PDF, if your already resizing you have the context.

`roundedImage` taken from: [Canvas drawimage with round corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19585999/canvas-drawimage-with-round-corners)

For example (wont work on SO, so no demo):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf@latest/dist/jspdf.min.js"></script>

    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      body {
        background: #ccc;
      }
      #pdf {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <embed id="pdf" src="#" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%" />
    <script>
      function roundedImage(ctx, x, y, width, height, radius) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x + radius, y);
        ctx.lineTo(x + width - radius, y);
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y, x + width, y + radius);
        ctx.lineTo(x + width, y + height - radius);
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo(
          x + width,
          y + height,
          x + width - radius,
          y + height
        );
        ctx.lineTo(x + radius, y + height);
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + height, x, y + height - radius);
        ctx.lineTo(x, y + radius);
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x + radius, y);
        ctx.closePath();
      }

      var img = new Image();
      img.src = "https://graph.facebook.com/649650002/picture?type=square";
      img.setAttribute("crossorigin", "anonymous");

      img.onload = function() {
        //
        const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        roundedImage(ctx, 0, 0, 50, 50, 5);
        ctx.clip();
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
        ctx.restore();

        // Default export is a4 paper, portrait, using milimeters for units
        var doc = new jsPDF();

        doc.text("woop!..rounded corners.", 10, 15);
        doc.addImage(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"), "PNG", 15, 25, 30, 30);

        document.getElementById("pdf").src = doc.output(
          "dataurlstring",
          "its-a.pdf"
        );
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```